# got error when installing spacy

Tags: python, spacy

I got error when installing spacy with pip (under mac python3). Following is the last part of the error report. It seams that there are much error. How can i fix it? I have installed gcc.

```
gcc: warning: x86_64 conflicts with i386 (arch flags ignored)
  cc1plus: warning: command line option '-Wno-strict-prototypes' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
  g++-4.2 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/thinc/linalg.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/thinc/linalg.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  unable to execute 'g++-4.2': No such file or directory
  error: command 'g++-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

.......

```
/usr/local/bin/gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -I/private/var/folders/md/8kgtqqz12j94hbcvhqz0w7gw0000gp/T/pip-build-sm84mnwa/murmurhash/murmurhash/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c murmurhash/mrmr.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/murmurhash/mrmr.o -O3 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function
gcc: warning: x86_64 conflicts with i386 (arch flags ignored)
gcc: error: murmurhash/mrmr.cpp: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
error: command '/usr/local/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
```

> Command
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c
>   "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/md/8kgtqqz12j94hbcvhqz0w7gw0000gp/T/pip-build-sm84mnwa/murmurhash/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /var/folders/md/8kgtqqz12j94hbcvhqz0w7gw0000gp/T/pip-4_7dl2wl-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/var/folders/md/8kgtqqz12j94hbcvhqz0w7gw0000gp/T/pip-build-sm84mnwa/murmurhash/

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure if this is related or not but I saw a discussion this morning that said that the latest macOS upgrade (Catalina) drops support for 32-bit applications altogether. The reason I mention it is because the x86_64 conflicts with i386 could be referencing the 32-bit/64-bit problem.

Have you recently upgraded your Mac OS? And if so, maybe you need to upgrade your dependencies to 64-bit equivalents?